# See my custom entity as a normal page in drupal 8

Tags: entities

I created a custom entity with the drupal 8 console. Everything works well. However, when I am logged in as an administrator, my entity appears in an admin page instead of a normal page like for nodes.

In this case, the title and the edit links (tabs) are displayed in the gray bar of the administration.

How to make my entity appear as a node without the gray bar of aministration?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Then you have probably defined an admin path to view the entity:

*/src/Entity/MyEntity.php*

```
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/structure/my_entity/{my_entity}",
```

Change this to a non admin path:

```
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/my_entity/{my_entity}",
```